# angular2 uploading file using ng2-uploader

Tags: angular

I am new in angular2. I am uploading file using ng2-uploader.
I html i am using below code:

```
   <input type="file" ngFileSelect [options]="options" (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)" (beforeUpload)="beforeUpload($event)">
```

In component:

```
    uploadFile: any;
    hasBaseDropZoneOver: boolean = false;
    options: Object = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload'
    };
```

In module.ts:

```
   import { Ng2UploaderModule } from 'ng2-uploader';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the **handleUpload** and **beforeUpload** in the component
Something like this :

```
 handleUpload(data): void {
     if (data && data.response) {
         data = JSON.parse(data.response);
         this.uploadFile = data;
     }
 }

fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
}

beforeUpload(uploadingFile): void {
    if (uploadingFile.size > this.sizeLimit) {
      uploadingFile.setAbort();
      alert('File is too large');
    }
}
```

For a complete code, go through the [following link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-uploader#basic-example) and check to see if you are missing any thing

Comment: I am following same link and using function "handleUpload" and "fileOverBase" and "beforeUpload" . Its showing correct error in i upload more than file size but i file size is ok than its showing me error: "ERROR TypeError: this.files.filter is not a function at NgFileSelectDirective.onChange (ng-file-select.ts:70) "  ....@Ozesh

Answer (score 0):

Try to using these options.

```
 options: object = {
 url: 'http://localhost://sitename/api/uploader.php',
    filterExtensions: false,
   allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png']
  };
```